# Testing a Retrofit + Moshi ApiService which returns a Deferred Object

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines, web-api-testing, moshi

I've been trying to build tests for the following API Service, but I can't figure how to build a mock interface for it:

```
package com.example.themovieapp.network

import com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineCallAdapterFactory
import com.squareup.moshi.Moshi
import com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapterFactory
import kotlinx.coroutines.Deferred
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Query

private const val BASE_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/"
private const val API_key  = ""

private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()


interface MovieApiService{
//https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-top-rated-movies
//https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Query.html
    @GET("movie/top_rated")
    fun getMoviesAsync(
        @Query("api_key") apiKey: String = API_key,
        @Query("language") language: String = "en-US",
        @Query("page") page: Int
    ): Deferred<ResponseObject>
}


/*
Because this call is expensive, and the app only needs
one Retrofit service instance, you expose the service to the rest of the app using
a public object called MovieApi, and lazily initialize the Retrofit service there
*/
object MovieApi {
    val retrofitService: MovieApiService by lazy {
        retrofit.create(MovieApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

I want to create Unit tests which:

Verify HTTPS status &

Verify that the JSON response is appropriate.

If it's any help, this is used in another file to create the API request:

```
coroutineScope.launch {
            val getMoviesDeferred = MovieApi.retrofitService.getMoviesAsync(page = pageNumber)
//...
            val responseObject = getMoviesDeferred.await()
//...
}

data class ResponseObject(
    val page: Int,
    val results: List<Movie>,
    val total_results: Int,
    val total_pages: Int
)
```

Comment: Probably do await() on the deferred. Which library for testing do you use? [kotest](https://github.com/kotest/kotest) utilizes coroutines for testing, based on JUnit and is concise.

Comment: ok I'll take a look at kotest for starters :) cheers
I'm an absolute newb to android testing, so I'm not even entirely sure what you mean by a testing library :|
I've been using jUnit4 so far though..
here's the project repo if you've any interest.
https://github.com/tomkeane07/TheMovieApp/tree/development/app/src/test/java/com/example/themovieapp

Thank you for my first ever stackExchange reply btw!

Comment: As an aside, this doesn't sound like a unit test - verifying https and json response of the service is testing someone else's service, or is an integration test, maybe. If you create a mock, you are testing your mock and not the real service.

Comment: Ok thank you. That’s a good point, I must test another page in my app which calls the service in its viewmodel, then binds it to a viewmodel.  So I guess I still have to use the mock api service to unit test this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with [MockWebServer](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/mockwebserver/okhttp3.mockwebserver/-mock-web-server/)

```
class MovieApiTest {
    private var mockWebServer = MockWebServer()

    private lateinit var apiService: MovieApiService

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        // checkthis blogpost for more details about mock server
        // https://medium.com/@hanru.yeh/unit-test-retrofit-and-mockwebserver-a3e4e81fd2a2
        mockWebServer.start()

        apiService = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
                .baseUrl(mockWebServer.url("/")) // note the URL is different from production one
                .build()
                .create(MovieApiService::class.java)
    }

    @After
    fun teardown() {
        mockWebServer.shutdown()
    }

    @Test
    fun testCompleteIntegration() = runBlocking { // that will allow to wait for coroutine
        mockWebServer.enqueue(MockResponse()
                .setResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                .setBody("""{
                    "page":0,
                    "total_results":1,
                    "total_pages":1,
                    "results": [{"id": "movie_id"}]
                }"""))

        val response = apiService.getMoviesAsync(page = 1).await()

        assertEquals(0, response.page)
        assertEquals(1, response.total_results)
        assertEquals(1, response.total_pages)
        assertEquals("movie_id", response.results.first().id)
    }
}
```

That way you can avoid calling the real server that won't work well in unit tests because of latency and non-deterministic network state.

Also, I do recommend splitting code in pieces so that you can test them independently if you have complex parsing logic: make the fields optional and define separate mapper that can check which parts of JSON are required, and which are mandatory, and test that mapper in isolation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think I asked the wrong question tbh.. 
I should have asked how to setup Unit Tests for the function which uses this API. I have posted that question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61665453/kotlin-coroutine-unit-testing-setup .
I won't delete this question out respect for the answer you provided though :) Thanks again

Comment: @Dmitry Sitnikov What would a sample mapper look like? Do you have a link to an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5067435/11m0 I don't have an exact example but a similar thing can be found here shorturl.at/dgsY5
The idea is that you have a single method interface (or a method reference) that takes data in the format retrofit returns it and converts field by field into the format that works best for the app (known as domain model). That way you can abstract away field names, join fields, remove unnecessary ones, do null checks etc. And if you use Gson I have an article about that https://proandroiddev.com/safe-parsing-kotlin-data-classes-with-gson-4d560fe3cdd2